# Angular - is there a way to let an event handler wait with its execution until the DOM has been updated?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, dom

Consider a dynamic table, i.e. a table, the rows of which are build dynamically:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let row of tableRows">
      <td>{{ row.id }}</td>
      <td>{{ row.name }}</td>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I am now adding a new entry to the component's variable `tableRows` and just after doing so, I emit an `addRow` event. The component, which I use this table in, handles the `addRow` event by scrolling the last table row into view.

The issue that I have is that the table row, which I have just added, is not yet available in my DOM at the time that I call `scrollIntoView`. However, it appears to be a matter of milliseconds, everything works fine when adding the following setTimeOut to my `addRow` event handler:

```
setTimeout(() => this.scrollRowIntoView(), 0);
```

I don't like the idea of having to use a `setTimeout` here. So, I wonder, is there a way to just wait until the DOM has been updated before calling `scrollIntoView()` ?

When implementing `AfterViewChecked` in my parent component, i.e. the component, which contains the table and the addRow-event-handler, I realized:

The `ngAfterViewChecked()` method is called AFTER `onAddRow`, i.e. the addRow-event-handler. Obviously, I want it to be the other way round and call `ngAfterViewChecked()` BEFORE `onAddRow`, because only then the DOM has been updated. Now, I cannot just call `onAddRow` inside `ngAfterViewChecked()` since I do not want to call this method every time the view has been checked, but only if the addRow event has been emitted.

I have managed to get this to work by introducing a boolean variable `rowAdded` to my parent component, which is toggled inside `ngAfterViewChecked()`. If this variable is true, I call `scrollIntoView` inside `ngAfterViewChecked()` and toggle the boolean variable afterwards.  In order for this to work, however, I still need to set the row that I want to scroll to inside my `onAddRow` event handler, because I set a property, which will be marked as "view changed after it has been checked" if I set it inside `ngAfterViewChecked()`.

It appears to me that it cannot be foreseen which method is executed first `ngAfterViewChecked` or `onAddRow` so that I tend to stick with my initial solution with `setTimeout`.

Comment: Have you tried in AfterViewInit or OnChanges? Also, if that doesn't work either, try adding trackBy to ngFor.

Comment: Show how you emit addRow event

Comment: @MishaMashina: AfterViewInit or AfterViewChecked? I want to call `scrollIntoView` after the adRow event has been fired, but only then, not if the view gets checked for any other reason. How can I implement this in AfterViewInit?

Comment: thx for the info considering `trackBy` and the `changeDetectorRef`. I looked into these features and they are great! But none of this seems to solve my problem. I think I am getting closer to a solution tho and have updated my question accordingly.